# How to run Python custom objects in separate processes, all working on a shared events queue?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have 4 different Python custom objects and an events queue. Each obect has a method that allows it to retrieve an event from the shared events queue, process it if the type is the desired one and then puts a new event on the same events queue, allowing other processes to process it.

Here's an example.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class CustomObject:

    def __init__(events_queue: mp.Queue) -> None:
        self.events_queue = event_queue

    def process_events_queue() -> None:
        event = self.events_queue.get()
        if type(event) == SpecificEventDataTypeForThisClass:
            # do something and create a new_event
            self.events_queue.put(new_event)
        else:
            self.events_queue.put(event)

    # there are other methods specific to each object
```

These 4 objects have specific tasks to do, but they all share this same structure. Since I need to "simulate" the production condition, I want them to run all at the same time, indipendently from eachother.

Here's just an example of what I want to do, if possible.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import CustomObject

if __name__ == '__main__':

    events_queue = mp.Queue()

    data_provider = mp.Process(target=CustomObject, args=(events_queue,))
    portfolio = mp.Process(target=CustomObject, args=(events_queue,))
    engine = mp.Process(target=CustomObject, args=(events_queue,))
    broker = mp.Process(target=CustomObject, args=(events_queue,))

    while True:
        data_provider.process_events_queue()
        portfolio.process_events_queue()
        engine.process_events_queue()
        broker.process_events_queue()
```

My idea is to run each object in a separate process, allowing them to communicate with events shared through the events_queue. So my question is, how can I do that?

The problem is that `obj = mp.Process(target=CustomObject, args=(events_queue,))` returns a Process instance and I can't access the CustomObject methods from it. Also, is there a smarter way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? Objects either communicate through the queue *or* via calling methods - but your description mentions both. Why do you use processes to *instantiate* the objects, instead of *running* already instated ones? I.e. why don't you do something like `worker = CustomObject(events_queue); mp.Process(target=worker.process_events_queue)`?

Comment: Your solution suggests that the 4 objects are all in the same process and only the call to `.process_events_queue()` is in a separate process. What I am asking is if it is possible to have objects living in "always-on separate process" that communicate between eachother through a shared queue.

Comment: A process must *do* something, you cannot have objects living separately by themselves. Since you want the objects to communicate via queues and `process_events_queue` is the only thing doing so, that is what you should run in a process. It may need generalising, yes, but how to do that is a very broad question for the general case.

Comment: So I can't have n different Python processes in idle, waiting to receive communication/work from another one, for an indefinite time?

Comment: Yes you can, by run-in something like `process_events_queue` as an infinite loop in a process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Processes require a function to run, which defines what the process is actually doing. Once this function exits (and there are no non-daemon threads) the process is done. This is similar to how Python itself always executes a `__main__` script.

If you do `mp.Process(target=CustomObject, args=(events_queue,))` that just tells the process to call `CustomObject` - which instantiates it once and then is done. This is not what you want, unless the class actually performs work when instantiated - which is a bad idea for other reasons.

Instead, you must define a main function or method that handles what you need: "communicate with events shared through the events_queue". This function should listen to the queue and take action depending on the events received.

A simple implementation looks like this:

```
import os, time
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process


class Worker:
    # separate input and output for simplicity
    def __init__(self, commands: Queue, results: Queue):
        self.commands = commands
        self.results = results

    # our main function to be run by a process
    def main(self):
        # each process should handle more than one command
        while True:
            value = self.commands.get()
            # pick a well-defined signal to detect "no more work"
            if value is None:
                self.results.put(None)
                break
            # do whatever needs doing
            result = self.do_stuff(value)
            print(os.getpid(), ':', self, 'got', value, 'put', result)
            time.sleep(0.2)  # pretend we do something
            # pass on more work if required
            self.results.put(result)

    # placeholder for what needs doing
    def do_stuff(self, value):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

This is a template for a class that just keeps on processing events. The `do_stuff` method must be overloaded to define what actually happens.

```
class AddTwo(Worker):
    def do_stuff(self, value):
        return value + 2


class TimesThree(Worker):
    def do_stuff(self, value):
        return value * 3


class Printer(Worker):
    def do_stuff(self, value):
        print(value)
```

This already defines fully working process payloads: `Process(target=TimesThree(in_queue, out_queue).main)` schedules the `main` method in a process, listening for and responding to commands.

Running this mainly requires connecting the individual components:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # bookkeeping of resources we create
    processes = []
    start_queue = Queue()
    # connect our workers via queues
    queue = start_queue
    for element in (AddTwo, TimesThree, Printer):
        instance = element(queue, Queue())
        # we run the main method in processes
        processes.append(Process(target=instance.main))
        queue = instance.results
    # start all processes
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    # send input, but do not wait for output
    start_queue.put(1)
    start_queue.put(248124)
    start_queue.put(-256)
    # send shutdown signal
    start_queue.put(None)
    # wait for processes to shutdown
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

---

Note that you do not need classes for this. You can also compose functions for a similar effect, as long as everything is pickle-able:

```
import os, time
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

def main(commands, results, do_stuff):
    while True:
        value = commands.get()
        if value is None:
            results.put(None)
            break
        result = do_stuff(value)
        print(os.getpid(), ':', do_stuff, 'got', value, 'put', result)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        results.put(result)

def times_two(value):
    return value * 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_queue, out_queue = Queue(), Queue()
    worker = Process(target=main, args=(in_queue, out_queue, times_two))
    worker.start()
    for message in (1, 3, 5, None):
        in_queue.put(message)
    while True:
        reply = out_queue.get()
        if reply is None:
            break
        print('result:', reply)
```

Comment: Very clear. It will take some time to test your solution but it sounds already like what I was looking for. I'll mark your reply as accepted when tested. BTW, I'm using classes instead of functions because it is easier to keep in mind all the different components as 'óbjects' instead of functions. Also, I'm using some of their attributes to store data for later use and so on, so classes are "easier" to implement. Please, if you think that there may be a clever way to achieve what I want to do, even without events and an events queue, feel free to open a private room with me. Thank you again.